# Android unable to open Gmail attachments

Tags: android, gmail, attachment

I would like to open pdfs attachments with my app.

I have set up the intent-filter

```
<intent-filter android:label="@string/label" >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/pdf" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/label" >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SHARE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/pdf" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent-filter>
```

and it works well on Android 4.4 devices but on 4.2.2 I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.google.android.gm.provider.MailProvider from ProcessRecord{2120ac60 21661:com.some.app.package/u0a10113} (pid=21661, uid=10113) requires com.google.android.gm.permission.READ_GMAIL or com.google.android.gm.permission.WRITE_GMAIL
```

I have tried adding all these permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.email.permission.READ_ATTACHMENT"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gm.permission.READ_GMAIL"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gm.permission.READ_CONTENT_PROVIDER"/>
```

Strangely if I try loading the same attachment but instead of using gmail I use default mail app, with same account, I get no errors.

but still get the same exception what can I do? thanks

EDIT:

I have also added these 2:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gmail.permission.READ_GMAIL"/> 
 <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gmail.permission.WRITE_GMAIL"/>
```

still no luck

EDIT2:

This is how I get the exception triggered:

```
public static byte[] getBytesFromUri(Uri uri, Context appCtx) {

    ByteArrayOutputStream byteBuffer = null;
    InputStream inputStream = null;

    try {
        inputStream = appCtx.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri); //crash here
        byteBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int bufferSize = 1024;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        int len = 0;
        while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            byteBuffer.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
        inputStream.close();
        inputStream=null;
        return byteBuffer.toByteArray();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.e(TAG, "error retrieving bytearray from uri "+uri);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

EDIT3:

Here is how I get the file uri:

```
Uri fileUri = null;
    if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        fileUri = intent.getData();
        intent.setData(null);
    } else if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        fileUri = intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
        intent.removeExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
    }
```

EDIT 4
for greenapps:
Here are the uris:

gmail

```
content://gmail-ls/gmail.account@gmail.com/messages/76/attachments/0.1/BEST/false
```

email

```
 file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.android.email/cache/test_file.pdf
```

So uris are different but they also are on 4.4 devices and it still works

Comment: is the uri different in `getBytesFromUri(Uri uri,` using GMail or Mail app?

Comment: @greenapps no, it's exactly the same logic

Comment: `the same logic` ? What do you mean by that? It should be the same uri.

Comment: sorry I had misread, so yes uris are different (see my EDIT4)

Comment: com.android.email.permission.ACCESS_PROVIDER

Comment: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/gmail/XD0C4sw9K7U/LpNXxFNnfgc

Comment: I have tried adding    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.email.permission.ACCESS_PROVIDER"/> but still get the same error, for the link it's about reading emails but I only want to have access to an attachment the system is himself passing to me. Plus why do we get this weird exception if the permissions they mention are no longer valid!

Answer (score 0):

USE BELOW CODE:
**INTENT FILTER**

```
  <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/octet-stream" />

            <data android:host="*" />
            <data android:scheme="smb" />
            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.pdf" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/octet-stream" />

            <data android:host="*" />
            <data android:scheme="smb" />
            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/pdf" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/octet-stream" />

            <data android:host="*" />
            <data android:scheme="file" />
            <data android:scheme="content" />
            <!-- Workaround to match files in paths with dots in them, like /sdcard/my.folder/test.pdf -->
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.pdf" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\.pdf" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\.pdf" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/octet-stream" />

            <data android:host="*" />
            <data android:scheme="file" />
            <data android:scheme="content" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/pdf" />
        </intent-filter>
```

In Activity Class convert **URI** to data using **CONTENT RESOLVER**

```
 TextView fileNameTextView;
private File file;

 Intent intent = getIntent();
    InputStream is = null;
    FileOutputStream os = null;
    String fullPath = null;

    try {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (!Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(action)) {
            return;
        }

        Uri uri = intent.getData();
        String scheme = uri.getScheme();
        String name = null;

        if (scheme.equals("file")) {
            List<String> pathSegments = uri.getPathSegments();
            if (pathSegments.size() > 0) {
                name = pathSegments.get(pathSegments.size() - 1);
            }
        } else if (scheme.equals("content")) {
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[] {
                    MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME
            }, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int nameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
            if (nameIndex >= 0) {
                name = cursor.getString(nameIndex);
            }
        } else {
            return;
        }

        if (name == null) {
            return;
        }

        int n = name.lastIndexOf(".");
        String fileName, fileExt;

        if (n == -1) {
            return;
        } else {
            fileName = name.substring(0, n);
            fileExt = name.substring(n);
          /*  if (!fileExt.equals(".gcsb")) {
                return;
            }*/
        }

        fullPath = ""/* create full path to where the file is to go, including name/ext */;

        String filenm = fileName + fileExt;
        file = new File(getCacheDir(), filenm);



        is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
        os = new FileOutputStream(file.getPath());

        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int count;
        while ((count = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            os.write(buffer, 0, count);
        }
        os.close();
        is.close();


        fileNameTextView.setText(fullPath);
        pdfView.fromFile(file)
        .enableSwipe(true) // allows to block changing pages using swipe
        .swipeHorizontal(false)
        .enableDoubletap(true)
        .password("123456")
        .defaultPage(0)
        .load();
        Log.e("TAG", "===onfile path: "+file.getAbsolutePath() );
        Log.e("TAG", "===onFile name: "+file.getName() );


    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (is != null) {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (Exception e1) {
            }
        }
        if (os != null) {
            try {
                os.close();
            } catch (Exception e1) {
            }
        }
        if (fullPath != null) {
            File f = new File(fullPath);
            f.delete();
        }
    }
```